# Linear interpolation between a set of points?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graphics

I have an array that contains x,y values. Now i can draw those points on the screen but i am having trouble interpolating between those points.

I have tried to search but everyone using different algorithms and its confusing me. I have tries Bresenham's line algorithm but i cant seem to understand it either.

```
var myVar = setInterval(function () {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 800);
    ctx.strokeRect(pts[q].x, pts[q].y, 20, 20);
    q++;
}, 1000/60);
```

pts has all the x,y cordinates and q is simply a variable to access the array. Now i can get the distance between the current point and the next point but then i get confused. I dont know what to do with that distance?

Can anyone please explain to me how it works? or point me to the right direction?

Comment: If A, B are points, then A(1 - x) + B(x) is a line that passes through those points. When x = 0, you are at A, and when x = 1, you are at B.

Comment: **What** do you want to interpolate?